# PHP & SQL - block an IP address after 3 or more entries in DB in short period of time

Tags: php, sql

please excuse the state of my code but I am fairly new. I am trying to write some PHP script to prevent an IP address from making more than three entries in my DB in a set period of time (preferably 1 hour but I don't know how to set that).

My code is below. All help greatly appreciated. I am currently getting the following error... "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''travisor_review' WHERE travisor_review.ip_address = '31.205.34.25' ' at line 2"

```
if (isset($_POST["leave"])) {

    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $queryTime = "SELECT * 
                    FROM 'travisor_review' 
                    WHERE travisor_review.ip_address = '$ip_address' 
                    ORDER BY date DESC
                    LIMIT 3";
    $resultTime = mysqli_query($conn, $queryTime) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultTime) > 3) {

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTime)) {
                $totalTime = $totalTime + (date("Y-m-d H:i:s") - $date);
            }

            echo $totalTime;

            if ($totalTime < 1000000) {
                exit("It seems you have been making too many reviews in a short period of time. Try again later.");
            }
        }

    $lreview = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lreview']);
    $srating = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['srating']);


    $query2 = "INSERT INTO travisor_review (tradesperson, rating, review, date, ip_address)
        VALUES('$id', '$srating', '$lreview', NOW(), '$ip_address')";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Comment: 1. Don't quote identifiers like that, eg: don't put single quotes around your table name. use backticks if you really want to. 2. [Use prepared statements.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) 3. 1 million seconds is 11.6 days.

Comment: I changed the issues you mentioned. SQL insert is now working but the script is not exiting on the 4th review inside 1 hour (3600 seconds). Any ideas?

Comment: @Sammitch Love your 1 million seconds example.

Comment: @RHamilton Using IP address to ban someone is ...., I want to say this in the nicest way... crude. What if 2 people in a train, connected by WiFi, want to submit a review, they're not allowed to? A logged in user has a `SID`, session ID. Track by that.

Comment: @Xorifeise thanks man, that's a good point. Just FYI this is for a uni project... like i said, I'm a beginner :)

Comment: `num_rows` can never be `> 3` because you used `LIMIT 3`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I had a small error in my SQL and undeclared variables in my Php. Code below...

```
 if (isset($_POST["leave"])) {

    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $queryTime = "SELECT * 
                    FROM travisor_review 
                    WHERE travisor_review.ip_address = '$ip_address' 
                    ORDER BY date DESC
                    LIMIT 3";
    $resultTime = mysqli_query($conn, $queryTime) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultTime) > 2) {

            $totalTime = 0;
            $date = $row["date"];

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTime)) {
                $totalTime = $totalTime + (date("Y-m-d H:i:s") - $date);
            }

            echo $totalTime;

            if ($totalTime < 3600) {
                exit("It seems you have been making too many reviews in a short period of time. Try again later.");
            }
        }

    $lreview = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lreview']);
    $srating = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['srating']);


    $query2 = "INSERT INTO travisor_review (tradesperson, rating, review, date, ip_address)
        VALUES('$id', '$srating', '$lreview', NOW(), '$ip_address')";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
```